# Passing string values

Tags: java

I have two frames and I want to move one frame's selected string value to another frame for opening database. In first frame I am using a `JComboBox` for picking values from my database. I need to to set the selected `JComboBox` value into a `String` for editing database. How can I do that?

I gave a small class in my program which is used to pic my values.

```
String carry=new String(user.getUserName());
```

This string I want to move to the next frame for picking the value for editing.

```
 public void populateFaculty() {
    ComboItem item = (ComboItem)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
    String userId = item.getValue();
    Users user = new Util().getUser(userId);

    String carry=new String(user.getUserName());

    loginIDJlabel.setText(user.getUserName());
    passwordJlabel.setText(user.getPassword());
    fullnameJlabel.setText(user.getFullName());
    System.out.println(user.getFullName());
    designationJlabel.setText(user.getDesignation());
    expJlabel.setText(user.getExp());
}
```

Comment: Your sample code is not clear with your question and password should not be displayed.

Comment: To hide the password, try a [`JPasswordField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html)

Comment: @vels4j @gobernador that's not the main problem to solve =\\ (and I hope that is just for testing purposes and it will be removed or hidden later). You should have a field in your second frame that will store this `String` new value instead of storing it in a `Component` as you're trying to do right now.

Comment: I dont want password field...I want to move my String carry to next frame.(How to pass string from one frame to another frame).I want that String (String value got perfect in this frame) for another frames edit purpose.thats why i am asking that

Comment: Post more code to be more clear. But perhaps what you want is to get the value from first frame to second with simething like `loginIDJlabel.setText(frame1.getCarry())`

Comment: No codes for details.Its confuse all.My motive is to pass String carry  to the next frame

Comment: Elias,Is ur code work at the frame2?

Comment: If you want to answer somebody in comments, use `@username` and an incoming message will appear on user inbox. To your question, looks like you didn't read my comment, you need a `String` field in your second frame that will hold the value of the data you want/need to pass. For example, `public class MySecondFrame extends JFrame { private String someData; //getter and setter... }` and before making create the instance of this frame visible, you can use `mySecondFrameInstance.setSomeData(item.getValue());`, now this will be available in your second frame and you can use it as you wish.